# I have 2 index as, which were 2 tables in sql as I can perform an inner joins query

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string

how I have 2 index one is called assignment and the other user in sql had a data field fk but I do not know how to perform an inner join in elasticsearch someone can support me

Answer (score 0):

So you have a couple options which might be useful, without knowing your specific use case I'm going to list a potentially useful links.

1) 
parent child mapping, really useful when you want to return all documents associated with a specific document. To make the mapping process a bit easier I typically index the data the retrieve the mapping using the /_mapping endpoint, modify the mapping, delete the index, then reingest the data. Sometimes that isn't an option in the case of short lived data.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-mapping.html

after updating the current mapping it's possible to use one of the joining queries.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html

2) 
When deleting the index and re ingesting the data isn't an option, create a new index, modify the data as described above, but instead of deleting the index use the re index API to get the information to the new index.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

3) 
It might also be possible to use an ingest processor to join the tables

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest-processors.html

4) 
possibly the quickest until you get your head wrapped around how elasticsearch works is to either join the information prior to ingesting or write a script joining the tables using one of the sdk's.

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html

plus a lot more build by the community.